# What's the difference between these snippets of code when using React setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What's the difference between the two?

```
this.setState((state)=>({
                posts: state.posts.filter(post=> post.id !==postRemoved.id)
            }))
```

and

```
this.setState((state)=>{
                posts: state.posts.filter(post=> post.id !==postRemoved.id)
            })
```

Comment: The main difference is that the second one wont work.

Comment: Implicit return utilizes parenthesis: `(args) => ();` while explicit return utilizes brackets: `(args) => { return null; };`. Same concept, but `setState` expects an object: `(args) => ({ ... })` or `(args) => { return { ... }; }`.

Comment: For reference, [implicit return](https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/17665/implicit-return) versus [explicit return](https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/17666/explicit-return)

Answer (score 1):

`setState` callback function expects an object to be returned. In the second case, you are just opening a function body without returning anything.

While wrapped with round brackets `()`, an object is returned instead. That's why the first option will work properly.